# page scrolling inconsistency between mobile Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

One feature of my mobile web app involves scrolling users to a particular point on the page. The following code accomplishes this, but it only works on iPhone Safari. On Chrome browser / Android, it scrolls to the bottom of the page instead. Why the inconsistency?

Please note: I don't want to use jQuery.

```
var $ = function(elID) {
    return document.getElementById(el); 
}

// Get info about target element's position and dimensions
var getRect = function(el) {
    return el.getBoundingClientRect(); 
}

var scrollJump = function(){
    var page = $('dPageContainer');
    headerHeight = getRect($('dFixedHeader')).height; 

    return function(el){
        // If a jQuery object, convert to raw DOM el
        if ('get' in el) {
            el = el.get(0); 
        }

        var rect = getRect(el); 

        // Scroll the page to the element's position
        page.scrollTop+= rect.top - rect.height - headerHeight;  
    }
};

var scrollToEl = scrollJump();

scrollToEl( $('my_DIV_ID') );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by simplifying and cleaning up the code. In particular, I used the `offsetTop` method instead of relying only on `getBoundingClientRect`:

```
var $ = function(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el); 
}

var scrollJump = function(){
    var page = $('dPageContainer'),
    headerHeight = $('dFixedHeader').getBoundingClientRect().height; 

    return function(el){
        // If a jQuery object, convert to raw DOM el
        if ('get' in el) el = el.get(0); 

        // Scroll the page to the element's position
        page.scrollTop = el.offsetTop - headerHeight; 
    }
};

var scrollToEl = scrollJump(); 
scrollToEl( $('my_DIV_ID') );
```